# Failed to fetch https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com/index.yaml : 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: hashicorp-vault, helm3

I'm following the next article: https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-minikube

When I'm trying to add the repo

```
helm repo add hashicorp https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com
```

I got an error

```
Error: looks like "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com/index.yaml : 405 Method Not Allowed
```

It seems the repo is broken or unavailable
Is that possible to install Hashicorp Vault/Consule without using such repo using Helm?

Answer (score 3):

It seems, happens because I'm from Russia

Hashicorp has [blocked access from Russia to all their services](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/access-to-releases-hashicorp-com-is-denied/36348):

> We’re sorry, but because of the conflict underway in Ukraine, HashiCorp is prohibiting availability of our products and services in Russia and Belarus.